# How to upload an uploaded image to carrier wave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, carrierwave

I want to upload an image which is already being uploaded to  my website. I want to show library to user and they will select one from it and it will be associated with the new record too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carrierwave gives you this feature to upload by providing the url. See the following code sample for help. Its taken from Ryan Bates railscasts. Its quite simple.
http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads
Simply add the :remote_image_url field and use it in your form, enter the url and leave the rest to Rails and Carrierwave.

```
class Painting < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :gallery_id, :name, :image, :remote_image_url
  belongs_to :gallery
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

you can refer [carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) home page

```
u = User.new
u.avatar = File.open('somewhere')
u.save!
```